# How to use forEach when iterating over collection objects MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

please suggest me how to make a selection from database comparing the ID in the collection with each element of the array?
Here is the code that unfortunately returns an empty array:

```
index(req, res) {
    Room.find({_id: req.user.rooms.forEach((item)=>{
            return item;
        })
    })
        .then((rooms) => {
            console.log(rooms)
            res.send(rooms)
        }
        )
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json(err));
}
```

**req.user.rooms** - each item of this array is ID, that I want to compare with what is in the collection Room.

Comment: if you add `console.log(item)` above `return item` what do you see?

Comment: there is no point of returning inside foreach, foreach is void

Comment: You are going about this in a really weird way. It's pretty straight-forward in their docs for how to [query items in a list](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/). In your case, the query should look like `Room.find({ _id: [/* all your values from req.user.rooms */]})....`. Going beyond that, you should really not be doing DB queries from your controller; [it's not a good architectural practice](https://dev.to/santypk4/bulletproof-node-js-project-architecture-4epf#architecture)

Comment: Thanks, sorry for my carelessness

Comment: No worries, we all start somewhere @maisteRR

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straight-forward in their docs for how to [query items in a list](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/).

Your code should look something like this:

```js
index(req, res) {
    // Additional validation should be done to make sure that req.user.rooms 
    // is an array with length > 0. I'll leave that for you to do.
    const rooms = req.user.rooms;

    Room.find({ _id: rooms})
        .then((rooms) => {
            console.log(rooms)
            res.send(rooms)
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(400).json(err));
}
```

---

Going beyond that, you should really not be doing DB queries from your controller; [it's not a good architectural practice](https://dev.to/santypk4/bulletproof-node-js-project-architecture-4epf#architecture) This is how it could look in your node service

#### roomController.js

```js
const RoomService = require("/path/to/services/directory"); // Let services contain all business logic. Don't give them anything related to your web server framework

async index(req, res) {
    // Additional validation should be done to make sure that req.user.rooms 
    // is an array with length > 0. I'll leave that for you to do.
    try {
       const rooms = await RoomService.retrieveById(req.user.rooms);
       res.send( { success: true, data: rooms } ); // We send back the result when we get one
    } catch ( err ) {
       // We respond to the client with our error, ideally you'll log it too
       res.status( err.statusCode ).send( { success: false, error: err } );
    }
    
}
```

#### RoomService.js

```js
const Room = require("/path/to/your/model");

module.exports = {
  retrieveById: async function(ids) {
     try {
       return await Room.find({ _id: ids}); // Typically this would be abstracted to a DB layer. but putting it here for brevity
     } catch( err ) { 
       throw new Error( err ); // This is caught in our controller, which we send to client
     }
     
  }
};
```